# Time complexity of a function with a recursive call that divides N by another Number that depends on N

Tags: recursion, time-complexity, big-o

```
void prime_factor(int n){
  if(n>1){
      int i= 2;
      while(n%i!=0){
          i++;
      }
      a[j] = i;
      j++;
          
      prime_factor(n/i);
  }
  

}
```

How to calculate the time Complexity of the above algorithm ? I know the loop runs n times (in worst case) but what  will be the complexity of only the recursion part ?

Comment: for each input, how many times does it recurse?

Comment: yeah that is the doubt !